# error 1136 con nuevas columnas en tabla mysql

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando con tablas en mysql me estaba funcionando bien pero le cree 2 nuevas columnas y al ejecutar me sale error?.

este es parte de mi código que ejecuto, hice registros nuevos cuando tenia 5 columnas y bien, pero agregue 2 nuevas columnas a la tabla y problemas:

```
e = (idEmpleados,numdocEmp,nombreEmp,salbasicEmp,fechaingEmp,nombre_eps,nombre_afp,fechanacEmp,sexoEmp)
cursor.execute("insert into Empleados values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", e)
```

este es el error:

> mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Comment: Jsierra intenta indicar de forma explícita las columnas donde quieres insertar los datos a ver que pasa: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Empleados (idEmpleados, numdocEmp, nombreEmp, salbasicEmp, fechaingEmp, nombre_eps, nombre_afp, fechanacEmp, sexoEmp) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", e)` Asegurate por supuesto que esos son los nombres de tus columnas en la tabla.

Comment: esas son todas las columnas, y se deben registrar todas con la opcion input, de hecho me pide todos los datos a registrar por cada columna, pero despues de ultimo registro aparece el erro, de no coincidencia entre columnas de registro y creadas??

Comment: las dos ultimas son la nuevas columnas creadas, antes funcionaba ok.

Comment: El error lo único que dice es que estas intentando ejecutar una consulta donde el número de columnas no concuerda con el número de valores. Por eso te digo lo de probar haciendo explícitas el nombre de las **nueve** columnas, a ver si te dice que alguna no existe o si inserta de forma adecuada.

Comment: ya descubri en el modulo de mysql que dos llaves foraneas que borre en workbench, me siguen apareciendo.

Comment: ahora como hago para borrarlas de mysql?

Comment: porque en workbench no aparecen esas columnas?

Comment: Para eliminar una clave foránea creo que era `ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name;` En cuanto a lo de workbench no creo poder ayudarte mucho, hace bastante desde la última vez que lo use y fue poco tiempo.

Comment: gracias hombre por tu tiempo,